# How to search the sentence stored in a List<string> in a file (Java)

Tags: java, apriori

I have two files itemsets.txt and combination.txt

itemsets.txt contains the detais of items bought by the customers.

```
Butter Bread Jam 
Bread Jam Cheese Tea 
Bread Eggs Coffee 
Tea Coffee Biscuits 
Biscuits Tea 
Nutella Cheese Eggs 
Maggie Coffee 
Eggs Jam Tea 
Maggie Tea 
Biscuits Coffee 
Bread Biscuits Cheese 
Biscuits Nutella 
Coffee Eggs 
Jam Biscuits 
Eggs Bread Biscuits
```

combination.txt contains the all the possible combinations of the items whose support is greater then the average support.

```
 Bread 
 Jam 
 Bread Jam 
 Cheese 
 Bread Cheese 
 Jam Cheese 
 Bread Jam Cheese 
 Tea 
 Bread Tea 
 Jam Tea 
 Bread Jam Tea 
 Cheese Tea 
 Bread Cheese Tea 
 Jam Cheese Tea 
 Bread Jam Cheese Tea 
 Coffee 
 Bread Coffee 
 Jam Coffee 
 Bread Jam Coffee 
 Cheese Coffee 
 Bread Cheese Coffee 
 Jam Cheese Coffee 
 Bread Jam Cheese Coffee 
 Tea Coffee 
 Bread Tea Coffee 
 Jam Tea Coffee 
 Bread Jam Tea Coffee 
 Cheese Tea Coffee 
 Bread Cheese Tea Coffee 
 Jam Cheese Tea Coffee 
 Bread Jam Cheese Tea Coffee
```

I want to search for the combinations in the itemsets.txt file. If the string in the combination.txt is present in the file itemsets.txt then the string will be get copied in a new .txt file.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you please convert the images into code text in your question?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous please check it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file contents of itemsets.txt and store it in an array. Now read each line from combinaton.txt and look for the match in itemsets.txt. If it matches you can store the same in the new file. Google for the standard file read and write codes it should be easily available.
Example: 
Input:

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader(FILENAME);
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Now br.readLine() should give you the inputs.
Output:

```
String str = "Hello";
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
writer.write(str);
```

Hope it helps.